# Find the APR at which total interest paid exceeds principal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I had an assignment to calculate details about a mortgage and I did that just fine. One of the things that caught my curiosity was that the interest rate offered, **3.247% APR**, did not produce a total interest paid that exceeded the principal. I thought in fact that it generally did.

The formula I believe I should be using is:

$P*\frac{i*(1+i)^n}{(1+i)^n-1}$

At what APR would the bank collect as much in interest paid as the principal loaned? I can see that it is roughly 5.3%, but I want to find it exactly.

I was looking at a **30 year fixed rate** on **74900** (with **20% downpayment**, so the principal was **59920**). I would like to accept either a specific answer or a general one that I can apply, either will do nicely.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer the question. Other information I'd need would include 1) how often are payments made, 2) is the interest rate 3.247/# of payments per year, or is it some other method, and 3) there are probably other fees associated with the mortgage which further complicate the problem.

Comment: You should probably consult a professional who knows the details behind your mortgage for this - as extra fees could contribute to your interest as well.

Comment: If you understand the formulae in use, and you have Excel, a good way to study this is 'goal seek' on the APR or interest rate.  It'll depend on the term though - you are looking for (sum all repayments) = 2 x (Original Loan) is that right?

Comment: That was just an exercise, and it is a monthly payment like many mortgages.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton - yes that is right :) Thank you I will lookk up goal seek -- see if I can find the mathematical basis for it.

Comment: The thing about financial problems like this is you need three of the following four things: the frequency of payments, the interest rate, the initial amount, and the payment amount. Thus, if you want us to give you an interest rate, we need to make an assumption on what the monthly payment amount is.

Comment: I get 0.076779297 or 7.68%

Comment: If you don't believe me, consider the following scenario: theoretically, you could pay off your entire loan in your very first month. If you do this, your interest will obviously be smaller than your principal.

Comment: sorry I got 5.72%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payment and interest scale with principal, so we may as well take the principal to be $1$ and the total of payments $2$.  This gives $$360\frac i{1-(1+i)^{-360}}=2$$  Which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=360*x%2F(1-(1%2Bx)%5E(-360))%3D2) solves with $i \approx 0.004420$ and an annual rate of $$5.304\%$$  You can't solve this equation algebraically for the interest rate.  It has to be done numerically.

Comment: thank you! I have some questions still, even thought this is my answer. That looks like an equation to me, why do you say numerically instead of algebraically (sorry, I just forget these terms specifically). Is there any simplification going on at the numerator (since principal is 1)? And, why did you use this formula (besides it being correct)? -- it looks very much like the formula for calculating monthly payments, actually.

Comment: Having $i$ both in an exponent and as a variable is the problem.  If it were only in exponents, you might be able to take a log.  My equation is the same as yours, I just remember it in this form.  I have just divided numerator and denominator by $(1+i)^t$ and set $P$ to $1$.

Comment: you can't solve it with logs, you need a numerical method, typically guessing and log/linear interpolation - but you could use Newton Raphson

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the principal is $\$59, 920$.

Let the monthly interest rate be $j$, so that $(1+j)^{n} = 1 + i$, where $i$ is (what we will assume) is the APR. [This is not necessarily going to be the case.]

Suppose that we make monthly payments of $M$.

At each month $t = 1, 2, \dots, 360$, we have $I_t = jB_{t-1}$, $I_t$ being the interest portion of the payment, and $B_{t-1}$ denoting the previous balance. Each payment consists of a principal portion and interest portion, for which $M_t = M = I_t + P_t$.

We wish to sum
$$\sum_{t=1}^{360}I_t = j\sum_{t=1}^{360}B_{t-1}\text{.}$$
Consider $B_0$: this is  $59,920$.

$B_1$ is given by the present value of future payments at interest rate $j$: this is going to be given by $$M\left[\dfrac{1-(1+j)^{-359}}{j} \right]\text{.}$$

Repeating this process, we get
$$Mj\sum_{t=0}^{359}\dfrac{1-(1+j)^{-(360-j)}}{j}$$
as the total interest paid. We wish to solve 
$$Mj\sum_{t=0}^{359}\dfrac{1-(1+j)^{-(360-j)}}{j} > 59,920\text{.}$$
Notice we may simplify the left side:
$$Mj\sum_{t=0}^{359}\dfrac{1-(1+j)^{-(360-j)}}{j} = M\left[360-\sum_{t=0}^{359}(1+j)^{-(360-j)}\right]$$
and the series 
$$\sum_{t=0}^{359}(1+j)^{-(360-j)} = \dfrac{1-(1+j)^{-360}}{j/(1+j)}$$
so our final equation is
$$M\left[360-\dfrac{1-(1+j)^{-360}}{j/(1+j)}\right] > 59,920$$
and this needs to be solved numerically.

This, furthermore, shows that we need to be given $M$ in order to solve for $j$.

Comment: in the UK they work out the payment based on an annual payment in advance, then divide it by 12, so I understand - but the APR is based on actual monthly interest effects - you can do better than summing all of the (1+i), it can be reduced to the formula given in the question using algebra

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Simplified.

Answer (score 0):

at i = 5.72%

30 year term

principal = 59,920

term = 30

$$payment = 59920 / 12 / ((1 - (1 + i)^{30}) / (1 - 1 / (1 + i)))$$

$$ = 59920 / 12 / 15 = $$

$$=332.90pm$$

Comment: that's wrong though, I used the formula for advance payments